# Sending data to activity

Tags: android, android-activity

So,I am trying to find out a way to send data to an activity WITHOUT starting it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY, message);
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there a way to do it without the(?):

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: walk us through what you want to accomplish here

Comment: what actually you want to do ? if you don't want to start another Activity, what is the need to pass data?

Comment: I just want to know if this is possible ,I am not trying to acomplish anything.I am still in the process of learning some stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you don't want to start an activity and pass the data then why to worry so much? Make the variable `public` and from the other `activity` class call the previous activity as follows and access that particular variable

```
((FirstActivity)getActivity()).theVariable
```